# C# Async UDP networking, 10057 error

Tags: c#, networking, udp

I have been trying to get this asynchronous UDP server working for the past two days and am banging my head against the wall now.

I am currently running into getting a `SocketException` for 10057 when I am trying to get `RemoteEndPoint` from the `Socket` in the `ReceiveCallback`.

When looking with the debugger `socket` is filled, `state` is filled. `LocalEndPoint` is normally set to `{0.0.0.0:53}`, yet `RemoteEndPoint` says a `SocketException` was thrown. And I do not understand what I am missing in my set up. Any helps, tips, guidance welcome.

```
namespace UDPServer
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;

    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket
        public Socket socket = null;

        // Size of the receive buffer
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;

        // Receive buffer
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }

    public class ServerAsync
    {
        private static int portNumber = 53;
        public static ManualResetEvent WaitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public static void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);
            EndPoint client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            socket.Bind(localEndPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("Listening for UDP queries on port 53");

            while (true)
            {
                // Set event to non-signaled state.
                WaitEvent.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                StateObject state = new StateObject();

                state.socket = socket;
                socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref client, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                WaitEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal main thread to continue.
            WaitEvent.Set();

            int bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                if (ar.IsCompleted)
                {
                    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                    Socket socket = state.socket;

                    IPEndPoint sender = (IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint;
                    EndPoint remoteEndPoint = (EndPoint)sender;

                    bytesRead = socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref remoteEndPoint);

                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes from {1}:{2}: {3}", bytesRead, sender.Address.ToString(), sender.Port.ToString(), BitConverter.ToString(state.buffer));

                        socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ref remoteEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: " + se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket closed: " + ode.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server starting up...");

            StartListening();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is your main thread looping and reading from the port when the EndCallback is also starting a new read? It looks to me like two threads will be trying to read from the port simultaneously, using the same StateObject.

Also, your receive callback is using the AsyncResult's buffer to start a new read operation. Do you know what the socket does with the AsyncResult object after you return? Can you be sure it doesn't dispose it? You may need to create a new AsyncResult for each read request so that they remain truly independent.

Comment: Jason, as far as I understood it, I thought that the loop was needed to service incoming connections, while the Begin*/End* with the additional Begin* inside the callback was for continuing receiving data from one source. But it could be my BSD sockets knowledge is intermingling with this API.

The reuse of the AsyncResult buffer is what I have seen in many examples, including Microsoft's documentation for `EndReceiveFrom`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b.aspx

Comment: Fair enough - I use UdpClient for UDP comms, so I'm not certain about the ins and outs of using lower level Socket APIs for this purpose. I am still unconvinced about having two async reads active concurrently though - a port gives a single stream of data, so it doesn't make sense to me to have two readers on it. But perhaps you are getting a separate stream for each endpoint?

Comment: I am fully open to switch to `UdpClient` again, but I ran into some issues on that front as well. Interesting point you raise about the streams though, it could be that I apply too much of a TCP mindset to this, but I need to add some TCP support to this as soon as I have this working. Maybe I need to go back to the blocking case and from there extend piece by piece until it is working, all the while making sure I fully understand every change I make.